# How do I add captcha validation in my D6 html content type form?

Tags: captcha

in our **Drupal6** site, one of the previous developers created a html form inside of one of the content types, so in the body of the content type, there is thml form code.  Users click submit and the values from the fields within that form are sent off via a url in the "

This method is being used in several places.  We want to add captcha to these older forms.

Going forward, we are using the webforms module and adding the captcha module to add a bit of security, but for these older html injected forms, I am not sure how to incorporate captcha.

I've added the captcha library, added the public key code in with the php code, captcha block appears on my page, but where i'm stuck is how to add the validation and private key for captcha.

In reading, it saids this validation code should be added on the other end.  This is not possible because the other end is a separate company that just takes our info/data.

The form action tag is like this https://wallacesales/main/memberstat/?......the rest of the url grabs the data from the fields 
so my question, on my end, in my D6 content type that uses html to create the form, how do I validate the captcha, if incorrect, tell user so they can reenter - if correct, then send it on to the above url

**Here is an example**
In content type the following html code resides to create the form.  I have added the captcha php that you see.  **So in this same form, how do I validate the captcha and then send the field values to the url you see in the form**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<body>
<h3>Send e-mail to someone@example.com:</h3>
<form action="https://wallacesales/main/memberstat/?…." method="post" enctype="text/plain">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" value="your name"><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail" value="your email"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" value="your comment" size="50"><br><br>
<?php
          require_once('sites/all/libraries/recaptchalib.php');
          $publickey = "lkjadkfj897d9s09dskdjfk09d9d9d";
          echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
        ?>
<input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Not sure show downgraded my question, but if you note in my question I have been researching the use of captcha.  To continue with my research.  I tried adding a function call to the action method of the form tag and created a echo function, but that function is not called. I get page not found error when i click submit.  Is this not possible within the confines of drupal and the content type?

Comment: The downvote is not from me, but it might be because you've answered your own question, rendering this a bit moot. You say, _"In reading, it saids this validation code should be added on the other end."_. So you know that you need to put the validation code on the other end. The fact that you can't _do_ that in your current project is not the fault of the module; logically speaking, you'll need to find another solution.

Comment: The google/captcha site references straight php/html forms, thus a html form  and processing pages would be created for their scenarios .  There is no reference to the implementation within Drupal, so I am trying to figure how to implement this case within a Drupal site that is using a non-conventential method, hence my question.

Comment: It seems that number of upvotes on comment by @Clive matches the number of downvotes on this question. It is pretty safe to assume what he wrote is the real reason.

Answer (score 0):

To me I see two solutions you could take.

One - you could client side validate using javascript.

Two - Two step the submit process. Change your form action to Submit to captcha installed on your site then submit to the url in the form.